# How can i change the Marker color clicked previously to its original color

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am displaying markers on a Google map .

When i click on the marker , i am setting it to different color (blue)

like this

```
        this.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png");
```

This is my full code

```
var map;
var global_markers = [];    
var markers = [[37.09024, -95.712891, 'trialhead0'], [-14.235004, -51.92528, 'trialhead1'], [-38.416097, -63.616672, 'trialhead2']];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.77627, -73.910965);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    addMarker();
}

function addMarker() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        // obtain the attribues of each marker
        var lat = parseFloat(markers[i][0]);
        var lng = parseFloat(markers[i][1]);
        var trailhead_name = markers[i][2];

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        var contentString = "<html><body><div><p><h2>" + trailhead_name + "</h2></p></div></body></html>";

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Trailhead name: " + trailhead_name
        });

        marker['infowindow'] = contentString;

        global_markers[i] = marker;

        google.maps.event.addListener(global_markers[i], 'click', function() {
            this.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png");
            infowindow.setContent(this['infowindow']);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLuTg/1008/

My question is that when i click on another Marker , how can i set the prevous marker which is in blue color to its original color

Answer (score 1):

You already have an array of all your markers.  Loop over them, resetting their icons.

Either do this for all the markers, then set the current one to blue.  Or within the loop have an if statement checking if the one being looped over is the currently clicked one (I prefer the first option).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(global_markers[i], 'click', function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < global_markers.length; j++) {
        global_markers[j].setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png");
    }

    this.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png");
    infowindow.setContent(this['infowindow']);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original marker is the default marker.  To set it back to that call `setIcon(null)`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(global_markers[i], 'click', function () {
    for (var j = 0; j < global_markers.length; j++) {
        global_markers[j].setIcon(null);
    }
    this.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png");
    infowindow.setContent(this['infowindow']);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ZLuTg/1009/)

code snippet:

```js
var map;
var global_markers = [];
var markers = [
  [37.09024, -95.712891, 'trialhead0'],
  [-14.235004, -51.92528, 'trialhead1'],
  [-38.416097, -63.616672, 'trialhead2']
];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.77627, -73.910965);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  addMarker();
}

function addMarker() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    // obtain the attribues of each marker
    var lat = parseFloat(markers[i][0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(markers[i][1]);
    var trailhead_name = markers[i][2];

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var contentString = "<html><body><div><p><h2>" + trailhead_name + "</h2></p></div></body></html>";

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "Trailhead name: " + trailhead_name
    });

    marker['infowindow'] = contentString;

    global_markers[i] = marker;

    google.maps.event.addListener(global_markers[i], 'click', function() {
      for (var j = 0; j < global_markers.length; j++) {
        global_markers[j].setIcon(null);
      }

      this.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png");
      infowindow.setContent(this['infowindow']);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```